# Thunderbird intermittent connection timeout with Office365

Tags: thunderbird, office365, connection, timeout, exchange-online

Our company has recently switched from Kerio Connect on-premises email server to Exchange Online. We had been using Thunderbird and had no problems previously.

After switching to Exchange, Thunderbird is intermittently throwing Connection Timeout errors. Because multiple users can be sharing an inbox, this causes a great deal of confusion because once the connection times out, the inbox is no longer the same as the other users and they do a lot of moving emails and renaming the subject (using header tools). I am using OAUTH2 for authentication. The timeout might happen a few times a day for each user and it sometimes only lasts for a few seconds and they are back in again. Sometimes it lasts for a few minutes. There is also a user at a different site which it occurs for as well.

I have tried:

- Ignoring Thunderbird process and folders in Windows Defender Antivirus.
- Increasing the timeout in Thunderbird (mailnews.tcptimeout)
- Reinstalling Accounts
- Updating Thunderbird to the latest version.
- Updating Windows.

It doesn't seem to happen to all users at the same time even though they are sitting next to each other.

It is the first time using Office365 so I am not used to it, but I can't find anywhere in there to diagnose failed connections, etc.

Does anyone know how I can get to the bottom of this issue?

Further Info based on Rohit Gupta's reply:

- We are using IMAP.
- All users are on Windows 10.
- Different users get the error message intermittently, but not all at the same time.
- The account is a shared mailbox with 6 users
- I found the sign-in history in Azure AD and there is no log for when the connection timed out.

Further Info based on Geeky51's reply:

- Some users are working from and have a different IP address and it happens for them intermittently too.

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more information. It sounds like you are using thunderbird on a windows machine and using IMAP and SMTP protocols but you might have also installed a thunderbird addon like "Owl" or "Tbsync" or "Exqulla" that can connect using exchange activesync protocols.  And some users might also be using linux or osx.  Are users only having trouble with a single shared account, or do they also have trouble with individual accounts on the same server?

Comment: I added more info to the question

Comment: OK.  You are indicating that the error issues a "connection timeout" message. I am not sure whether this will help, but you might try this solution for 
[reducing the number of connections to the server](https://electrictoolbox.com/thunderbird-exceeded-maximum-connections-imap-server/) being used by each user. You need to change the setting on all machines for all users to see the benefit I think.

Comment: I can try it. However, some of the users are working from home and have a different IP address, and they also get the timeout message intermittently.

Comment: did the number of connections solution help? Note that solution is addressing a server limit, not a client limit, so if it helps,  it would help all your users, regardless of whether they are at work or home

Comment: No. We still had problems. We ended up just using Outlook Online to get around it for now.